# Istio Virtual Service Relationship to Normal Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am watching a Pluralsight video on the Istio service mesh.  One part of the presentation says this:

> The VirtualService uses the Kubernetes service to find the IP addresses of all the pods.  The VirtualService doesn't route any traffic through the [Kubernetes] service, but it just uses it to get the list of endpoints where the traffic could go.

And it shows this graphic (to show the pod discovery, not for traffic routing):

[image: VirtualService uses Service to get IPs of pods]

I am a bit confused by this because I don't know how an Istio `VirtualService` knows which Kubernetes `Service` to look at.  I don't see any reference in the example Istio `VirtualService` yaml files to a Kubernetes `Service`.

I have theorized that the `DestinationRules` could have enough labels on them to get down to just the needed pods, but the examples only use the labels `v1` and `v2`.  It seems unlikely that a version alone will give only the needed pods.  (Many different `Services` could be on `v1` or `v2`.)

**How does an Istio `VirtualService` know which Kubernetes `Service` to associate to?**

or said another way,

**How does an Istio `VirtualService` know how to find the correct pods from all the pods in the cluster?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When creating a VitualService you define which service to find in `route.destination` section

`port` : service running on port

`host` : name of the service

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  hosts:
  - "example.com"
  gateways:
  - test-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 80
        host: app-service
```

so,

`app-pod/s` -> (managed by) `app-service` -> `test` virtual service

Comment: I thought that the `route.destination` section was used to choose the `DestinationRule`.  How then does the `VirtualService` associate to a `DestinationRule`?

Comment: same way we create a `kind` : `DestinationRule` which will pick up service and add routing rules

Istio has amazing documentaion: 
https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/

Answer (score 6):

Arfat's answer is correct.

I want to add the following part from the docs about the host, which should make things even more clear.
https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#VirtualService

> [...] Note for Kubernetes users: When short names are used (e.g. “reviews” instead of “reviews.default.svc.cluster.local”), Istio will interpret the short name based on the namespace of the rule, not the service. **A rule in the “default” namespace containing a host “reviews” will be interpreted as “reviews.default.svc.cluster.local”**, irrespective of the actual namespace associated with the reviews service. To avoid potential misconfigurations, it is recommended to always use fully qualified domain names over short names.

So when you write `host: app-service` and the `VirtualService` is in the `default` namespace, the host is interpreted as `app-service.default.svc.cluster.local`, which is the FQDN of the kubernetes service. If the app-service is in another namespace, say `dev`, you need to set the host as `host: app-service.dev.svc.cluster.local`.

Same goes for `DestinationRule`, where the FQDN of a kubernetes service is defined as host, as well.
https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#DestinationRule

`VirtualService` and `DestinationRule` are configured for a host. Both are an abstraction for configuring `Envoy` running as the istio gateway/sidecar. The `VirtualService` defines where the traffic should go (eg host, weights for different versions, ...) and the `DestinationRule` defines, how the traffic should be handled, (eg load balancing algorithm and how are the versions defined.

So traffic is not routed like this

Gateway -> VirtualService -> DestinationRule -> Service -> Pod, but like

Gateway -> Service, considering the config from VirtualService and DestinationRule.